# iOS Quickblox QBRequest error in QBGeneralResponsePage

Tags: ios, quickblox

i'm updating my app to the SDK 2.0.10 and I'm having some problems with QBRequest blocks:

```
[QBRequest usersForPage:[QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:0 perPage:100] 
successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *page, NSArray *arrayOfUsers) {...}
```

`QBGeneralResponsePage` result give invalid results, in every sample i've try, and in my own app:

```
page.totalEntries = 18446744073709551615
```

There is also a problem with:

```
[QBRequest downloadFileWithUID:(NSString *) successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSData *fileData) {
//        <#code#>
    } statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {
//        <#code#>
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
//        <#code#>
    }]
```

The result in `NSData *fileData` it's an invalid Data, so if you try to use it in `[UIImage imageWithData:fileData];` the result is nil

Do you have any idea about how to solve it??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out iOS SDK 2.0.11

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Download_iOS_SDK

It works there

Comment: Please answer to the following question, its need some attention!
[How to check whether session live or expired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074234/how-to-check-whether-session-live-or-expired-in-quickblox-ios-sdk) [How to filter users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060067/how-to-filter-quickblox-users) [How to filter users based on their mobile number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055128/how-to-filter-quickblox-user-based-on-his-phone-number) Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Thank you! The response of downloadFileWithUID it's still not working, right?