# How to filter quickblox user based on his phone number?

Tags: ios, filter, quickblox

I'm able to filter users with their phone numbers using `[QBRequest usersWithPhoneNumbers:]` method, but having problem with following scenario.

Suppose, I've a quickblox user with `1234567890` phone number in my app.
Now, in my contact list, I've the same phone number but with `+91` (caller code of India), so the number I in my phone book is, `+91 1234567890`, once I'll fetch all my contacts from phone book, it'll be look like, 911234567890 (`+` and `space` will be removed), and I'll query for quickblox user with the number I've fetched, and it'll return me [no user] because there's 91 in the number I'm requesting.

I think, quickblox comparing entire number and not the part of the number. That's the reason I'm not getting the user. Any idea to solve this?

I found a 3rd party library, which removes country code from the number, but I don't want to use it, because I want to make it general and not to dependent and more complex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, QuickBlox compares entire string, there is no intelligent comparison. So the only solution for you right now is to remove country code from phone number before saving user to QuickBlox.