# How to check whether session live or expired in Quickblox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, session, quickblox

I know that, any session will be expired after last request (made before 2 hours) to the Quickblox server. When I create a session, I'm able to find `[QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate` but I'm not sure how it works and how should I check for whether session is live or expired?

1. How to check whether session is live or expired?
2. If I create a session, I'll get  `[QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate` for next 2 hours, now within an hour I'll made a request to the server, would it update `[QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate` date too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By checking *tokenExpirationDate*.
2. *tokenExpirationDate* is updated in every response from QuickBlox. So answer is - yes.